# Vector - Total score from course record.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

The record for each student in a class is given as a 10-
vector r, where r1, . . . , r8 are the grades for the 8 homework assignments, each on a 0–10
scale, r9 is the midterm exam grade on a 0–120 scale, and r10 is final exam score on a
0–160 scale. The student’s total course score s, on a 0–100 scale, is based 25% on the
homework, 35% on the midterm exam, and 40% on the final exam. Determine s such that the student's final grade is given by the inner product of s and r.

Please help, is my approach correct?
I reduced the 10-vector r to (80,120,160), supposing that the student had mastered all grades.
In order to find the vector s, I made the following equations based on each score scale:

80A=0.25

120B=0.35

160C=0.40

Therefore the 3-vector s would be (0.0031,0.0029,0.0025), and the inner product of s and r would give the student's final grade.

Comment: Help means that you are also involved in the solution. What have you tried? What don't you understand? Note that if the answer to my second question is "I don't understand how to do it" you will most likely leave empty handed.

Comment: Pardon me. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution seems close to correct; I take it you have taken $A$ to be the sum of all homework scores? In that case, I see only two minor problems:

1. Your scores now end up on a scale of $0$ to $1$. This is of course easily fixed by multiplying the vector by $100$.
2. You use rounded values for the vector, which can lead to the wrong results. This can be avoided by using fractions instead of decimals, or otherwise by rounding a few decimals further to avoid significant impact on the grades.

You should then end up with the vector
$$\left(\frac{25}{80},\frac{35}{120},\frac{40}{160}\right)=(0.3125,0.291666\ldots,0.25).$$

As a side note,  here's a how I originally approached the problem:

The total course score is on a $0$ to $100$ scale. The homework is $25\%$ of the score, so this is on a $0$ to $25$ scale. There are $8$ assignments, so each is on a scale of $0$ to $\tfrac{25}{8}=3.125$. So to convert the original homework scores from their $0$ to $10$ scales, multiply them by $0.3125$ to get them on a $0$ to $3.125$ scale.

The midterm and the final can be done in the same way, and then you can add up all the scores.